# Install Voila on SageMaker based Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, voila

I'm trying to run the Voila! server on a SageMaker Notebook.

Commands to install and enable voila:

```
!pip install voila
!jupyter serverextension enable --sys-prefix voila
```

The pip command appears to work OK.

Terminal output from the jupyter command:

> Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `EnableServerExtensionApp`.
> Enabling: voila
>
> - Writing config: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/etc/jupyter
>
>   - Validating...
>     voila 0.2.10 OK

Navigating to a 'voila url' such as:

```
https://{instance}.notebook.{region}.sagemaker.aws/voila/sandbox/test-notebook.ipynb
```

Returns a 404.

The ***'nbextensions'*** tab shows the voila extension as 'possibly incompatible'

[image]

I can't find anything in the Jupyter logs that looks relevant.

Restarting Jupyter didn't help.